# Partitioning a given set into root set of two polynomials or non zero set of two polynomials simultaneously

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, fields

Let $p,q$ be two prime numbers and let $p<q.$ Also let, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_q$ denote the fields formed by integers modulo $p$ and modulo $q$ respectively (with respect to the modulo $p$ addition and multiplication and modulo $q$ addition and multiplication respectively).

Suppose we have a multivariate polynomial $P(x_1,x_2,.....,x_n)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p [ x_1,x_2,.......,x_n ],$ and a multivariate polynomial $Q(x_1,x_2,.......,x_m)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_q[x_1,x_2,..........,x_m].$

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a set of integers with $|\mathcal{A}|=m+n.$

What can be said regarding decomposition of $\mathcal{A}$ as $\mathcal{A}=(a_1,a_2,.....,a_n) \sqcup (b_1,b_2,..........,b_m),$ such that $P(a_1,........,a_n)=0,$ and $Q(b_1,........,b_m)=0 ?$

Furthermore, what can be said regarding decomposition of $\mathcal{A}$ as $\mathcal{A} = (c_1,c_2,...,c_n) \sqcup (d_1,d_2,.....,d_m)$ such that $P(c_1,....,c_n) \ne 0$ and also $Q(d_1,d_2,......,d_m) \ne 0 ?$

By saying "what can be said regarding decomposing $\mathcal{A}$ as ........", I mean to ask about results in this direction where (perhaps for specific types of polynomials $P$ and $Q$ and some particular type of sets $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$), such things are known or studied or can be said.